# how do I sort the queryset by a property's property? django

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-queryset

I have a function which returns a `queryset` but now I would like to sort the `queryset` but I am not sure how this can be done.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    print('--------------------------------')
    # print(self.request.basket.all_lines()[0].product.upc)
    print('--------------------------------')
    return self.request.basket.all_lines()
```

`self.request.basket.all_lines()` would return me a queryset but I would like to sort it by it's product's upc

I am able to get the upc by `print(self.request.basket.all_lines()[0].product.upc)`

I made sure that `.product.upc` does exist and I am in the right direction.

Can someone please give me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
return self.request.basket.all_lines().order_by('product__upc')
```

Comment: I would get something like `'Basket' object has no attribute 'order_by'` error though

Comment: What is the type of basket? `print(type(self.request.basket))`

Comment: Better yet, what's the the type returned by `all_lines`? `print(type(self.request.basket.all_lines()))`.

Comment: yours gave me an idea of using `self.request.basket.all_lines().order_by('product__upc')` which did work in a way for the sorting feels weird though

Comment: Weird in what way?

Comment: oh yes yes, your edited answer did gave me something but why is the ordering. `10000013` before `100004` then `100008` ? is this normal for sortings?

Comment: Depends on the type of `utc` field. Looks like it is `CharField` and therefore sorting works on strings (`'10000013' < '100004' < '100008'`). You should use `IntegerField` if you want order numbers.

Answer (score 0):

How about using python's `sorted` method?

`sorted(self.request.basket.all_lines(),  key=lambda x: x.product.upc)`

Comment: I would get an error like this though `'list' object has no attribute 'ordered'`

Comment: Because I can't add a comment above yet, Domen's answer needs `self.request.basket.all_lines().order_by('product__upc')`

Comment: Also I can explain why you get that error. I assume that comes after the sorting? Then that's because your QuerySet has been turned into a list. That's not the end of the world! You could pass that manually to the template or wherever.

Comment: No problem @DomenBlenkuš